# Using For loop in TypeScript Array and load items dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

Is it possible to populate items to an item array i.e. some part of [PrimeNG Menubar](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/menubar) by using a for loop? For example, I try to populate the "Teams" item of the following part, but cannot use for in the `items:[...]` field. So, in this case I cannot populate Teams dynamically an have to add statically. Any idea?

```
this.items = [
    {
        label: 'File',
        icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-file',
        items: [{
                label: 'New', 
                icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-plus',
                items: [
                    {label: 'Project'},
                    {label: 'Other'},
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        label: 'Teams',
        icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-ball',
        items: [
            {label: 'Team A', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-a'},
            {label: 'Team B', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-b'}
        ]
    },
];
```

Comment: You need to be more clear about your use case.  The object should probably built up before being assigned to this.items  I wouldn't be surprised if changes way down in this.items[1].items.push({})  go unnoticed by the component.

Comment: @Joe Thanks a lot. Actually there is a Team table in the database having label and icon fields. Assuming that there are  5 Teams in the database and I want to populate `{label: 'Team A', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-a'}` part 5 times. So, is it clear now? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think my problem is pushing items to the items[] array using loop. But I just want to add Teams part.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to iterate over, but you create a new Array with `n` entries and map those entries to your desired items.

```
this.items = [
    {
        label: 'File',
        icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-file',
        items: new Array(10) // Create a new array with 10 entries
           .fill(0) // Fill that array with zeroes --> [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
           .map((val, index) => ({ // supply a callback that takes each value and the index and returns anything else instead
               label: `New ${index}`, // Print the  
               icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-plus',
               items: [
                   {label: 'Project'},
                   {label: 'Other'},
               ]
           }))
    },
    {
        label: 'Teams',
        icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-ball',
        items: [
            {label: 'Team A', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-a'},
            {label: 'Team B', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-b'}
        ]
    },
];
```

Comment: Thanks for help but I assuming that there are  5 Teams in the database and I want to populate `{label: 'Team A', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-a'}` part 5 times. But you iterate File part instead of Teams part. What do you think? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think my problem is pushing items to the items[] array using loop. But I just want to add Teams part.

Comment: @hexadecimal I think your problem is that question is not clear. You never mentioned which part should be populated by data from a normal for loop. Also, you never mentioned where this data comes from. Add examples for where the data comes from and an explanation what you want to achieve so I can elaborate on those.